# Pointwise infimum of uncountably many measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $F$ be a family of measurable real functions on the domain $(0,1)$ satisfying the following two conditions:

(1) $f_1, f_2 \in F$ implies $\min\{f_1, f_2\} \in F$;

(2) $g = \lim_n f_n$  for some $\{f_n\in F: n\in \mathbb N\}$ implies $g\in F$;

[Claim] If we set $h = \inf \{f: f\in F\}$, then $h \in F$.

The motivation of the [Claim] is the following. We know infimum of countably many measurable functions is a measurable function. However, it is absurd to say that infimum of uncountably many measurable functions is again a measurable function. I wonder that, if it may be possible to have a measurable infimum, when we add two closedness conditions above to the family of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wrong. Let 
$$ F = \{f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbf R: f[(0,1)] \subseteq\{0,1\}, f^{-1}[\{0\}] \text{ is countable}\}$$
Then each $f \in F$ is measurable, the two closedness conditions are fulfilled, but $\inf F = 0 \not\in F$.

---

If you want $\inf F$ to be non-measurable, almost the same trick works. Let $A \subseteq (0,1)$ a non-measurable set, and set 
$$ F' = \{f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbf R: f[(0,1)] \subseteq \{0,1\}, f^{-1}[\{0\}] \text{ is a countable subset of $A$}\} $$
Then both closedness conditions are fulfilled (because a countable union of countable subsets of $A$ is a countable subset of $A$), but 
$$ (\inf F')(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in A \\ 1 & x \not\in A \end{cases} $$
is non-measurable.